# submit form data to wordpress existing database table using my plugin

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, forms, phpmyadmin

i have created a plugin for wordpress to sbmit form dtails to wordpress database. I created a table in cpanel phpmyadmin called 'wp_in_booking'.
im trying to send the form data, but it can not get through. Here is my code.Data is not sent to the database. please help. thank you

```
<?php
function in_booking_form(){ 
   ob_start();
    ?>
    <link href="<?php echo plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'/files/jquery.datetimepicker.css'; ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'/files/jquery.datetimepicker.js'; ?>"></script>

    <form class="in-checkout-form" action=""  method="post">
        <div class="in-booking-section">
        <input required type="text" id="date_timepicker_start" class="in-dates" name="check_in" placeholder="check-in">
        // there is other javascript code here

        <input type="hidden" name="total_amount" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="adults" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="children" value="0">
        <input type="hidden" name="infants" value="0">
      <input type="submit" class="in-request-to-book" value="Request to Book" name="submit">
    <?php 
      global $wpdb;

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // $table = $wpdb->prefix . "wp_in_booking";
    $check_in = $_POST['check_in'];
    $check_out = $_POST['check_out'];
    $total_amount = $_POST['total_amount'];
    $adults  =$_POST['adults'];
    $children = $_POST['children'];
    $infants = $_POST['infants'];

    $check_in_db=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($check_in));
    $check_out_db=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($check_out));

//    

    $result = $wpdb->insert('wp_in_booking', array(
      'check_in'=>$check_in_db, 
      'check_out'=>$check_out_db, 
      'total_amout' =>$total_amount,
      'adults'=>$adults,
      'children'=>$children,
      'infants'=>$infants

    ));
    if($result){
      echo "Booking Successful";
    }else{
      echo "Booking Unsuccessful! Please Contact Support";
      }

    }
   ?>
    </form>

    <?php

    return ob_get_clean();

}
add_shortcode('in_booking_form','in_booking_form');
```

and my database structure

[image]

Comment: "// there is other javascript code here" Such as? Does it do anything on form submission?

Comment: What is the value of  `$result` after you run the db query.  If an error was encountered; it should show there if you var-dump the variable.

Comment: @JacobPeattie
no, the Javascript is just for a few onclick additions.

@josh
 the link is working fine, because datepicker - which was the intended functionality is working fine.

`var_dump($result)` returns `false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found out where the problem was. the datatype for check_in and check_out in the database was set to `DATETIME` Instead of `DATE` yet the code `$check_in_db=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($check_in));` was converting it to date. I don't know why it prevented entry of the other data, but after changing that, it is working now. 
to use date time, use this  `$check_in_db=date("Y-m-d  H:i:s",strtotime($check_in));`